# not able to get performance boost with python concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor in SQL Server query

Tags: python, sql-server, python-3.x, pyodbc

I am querying SQL Server for the list of fields both with threading and without threading.

```
import pyodbc
import datetime
import concurrent.futures

server = 'xx.xxx.xxx.xxx,1433'
database = 'db'
username = 'user'
password = 'password'
cnxn = pyodbc.connect('DRIVER={ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server};SERVER='+server+';DATABASE='+database + ';UID='+username+';PWD='+password + ';MARS_Connection=yes' + ';Max_Pool_Size=100000')

filter_list = ["department_id", "employee_id", "city", "country", "state", "zip_cope", "department_name", "employee_name", "employee_experience"]
t1 = datetime.datetime.now()
result_list = []
def query_executor(field):
  try:
    
    ft1=datetime.datetime.now()
    cursor = cnxn.cursor()
    result = cursor.execute("""SELECT DISTINCT TOP 1000 [{}] from EMPLOYEE_DETAILS""".format(field))
    print(field)
    result_list1 = [filter_item[0] for filter_item in result if filter_item[0]]
    # print("#############################################")
    return {"name": field, "filter_data": result_list1}
  except Exception as e:
    print(e)
  finally:
    print("#############################################")
    print(datetime.datetime.now()-ft1)
    print("#############################################")
    cursor.close()

# with threading
with concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor() as executor:
  result = [executor.submit(query_executor, field) for field in filter_list]

  for f in concurrent.futures.as_completed(result):
    result_list.append(f.result())

          
print(result_list)
t2 = datetime.datetime.now()
print("#############################################")
print('with threading time taken')
print(t2-t1)
print("#############################################")


#without threading
for f in filter_list:
  result_list.append(query_executor(f))

          
print(result_list)
t2 = datetime.datetime.now()
print("#############################################")
print('without threading time taken')
print(t2-t1)
print("#############################################")
```

While running, I comment either of one to see the time taken individually with and without threading. But I don't see much time difference. In fact sometime threading one gets slow.

Am I doing something wrong? How will I get the performance boost? `filter_list` list can grow even bigger sometime, which may lead to slow response.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Using multiple threads is not a "magic bullet" that is guaranteed to improve performance in all cases. If the rate at which you can retrieve rows from the database is limited by unrelated factors like network bandwidth, disk I/O on the server, etc. then it won't really matter if your client application is single-threaded or multi-threaded. And, since using multiple threads makes your application work harder (to manage those threads) it may in fact make your app run slower.

Comment: @GordThompson Can you please suggest. how to make querying faster.

Comment: `Max_Pool_Size` [defaults to 100](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#system.data/fx/src/data/System/Data/SqlClient/SqlConnectionString.cs,46). Setting it to 100,000 isn't going to do anything but starve your python client system of memory and socket handles - specifically, [port exhaustion](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/client-management/troubleshoot-tcpip-port-exhaust).